# How to retrieve data which have been submitted through form using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, post

Morning peeps,

I have a PHP function which gets me 10 questions from my database, looping these through and populating it inside the form. For each question there is a possibility of 4 answers to choose from (multiple choice style).

For each of the answer record there is a column to state whether or not if it's correct. So if I can get the answer Id I would be able to check if its correct or not.

This is how my HTML looks:

```
<div class="quiz">
    <?php
        echo '
            <form id="level_quiz" name="upload_form" action="calculate_result" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

            foreach (get_questions($_POST['level_id']) as $questions) {
                echo '
                        <div style="background-color: #242424 ! important; margin-top: 30px;" class="container-fluid bg-info">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <input type="hidden" id="question[]" name="question[]" value="'.$questions['question'].'">
                                <h2 name="question" id="question" value="'.$questions['question'].'" style="font-size: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: -30px;color: white;">'.$questions['question'].'</h2>
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';

                foreach (get_answers($questions['questions_id']) as $answers) {
                    echo '
                        <div class="question_style form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input style="color: #ffffff" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[]" id="answer[]" value=" '. $answers['answer_id'] .' "> '. $answers['answer'] .'
                            </label>
                        </div>
                ';
                }

            }
        echo '<button style="float: right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></form>';
    ?>
</div>
```

PHP Functions :
get_questions()

```
function get_questions($id) {
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT course.name, course.level_type, quiz.name, quiz.total_questions, questions.question
    FROM `course`
    JOIN quiz using (course_id)
    JOIN questions using (quiz_id)
    JOIN answers using (questions_id)
    WHERE course.course_id = '$id'
    AND answers.correct = 1
    GROUP BY answers.questions_id
SQL;

    $result = get()->query($sql);

    $rows = resultToArray($result);
    return $rows;
}
```

This function will return me all the questions belongs to a level where the answer is the correct one so I can get the list of questions.

get_answers()

```
function get_questions_and_all_possible_answers($quetion_id) {
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `answers`
    WHERE `questions_id` = '$quetion_id'
SQL;

    $result = get()->query($sql);

    $rows = resultToArray($result);
    return $rows;
}
```

This function above gets me all the possible answer when I pass in a question id (as mentioned a question have 4 answer from where user can pick the correct one).

My issue here is that when I submit the form I get all 10 questions however I cannot see what the user has put down for each question. Is there some how I can change the code so I can get what user has selected for each question so that way I would be able to do a check at wherever I am posting the form to.

This is how currently the form submit looks like:

```
Array ( [question] => Array ( [0] => What is forex trading ? [1] => Currency pairs are usually represented by how many letters? [2] => The first two letters in a currency pair stand for? [3] => What does this stand for in trading terms NZD? [4] => What is the largest traded market? [5] => What does a liquid market mean for a trader? [6] => What is the largest traded currency? [7] => How are forex quotes arranged? [8] => Selling a currency to buy another is referred to in forex terms as? [9] => Which currency is the basis for the buy or the sell? ) [answer] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

I have tried my best to solve this however I couldn't and that is the reason for posting on here, if more details required please ask.

Thank You in advance.

Snapshot of the questions table :

```
https://gyazo.com/139d78ae9f71dfdda7a4e8c89d33a41b
```

Snapshot of the answers table:

```
https://gyazo.com/7fbd116f3bb9dd1d28c6e450d8c087c5
```

Snapshot of the course table (for each course there will be questions)

```
https://gyazo.com/61ab61c5a8a240cacf3ace72c10c656b
```

Comment: can you share the db or create a fiddle

Comment: I have provided some snapshots of the table, I hope that helps to clear my question

Comment: This really looks like it should work.... Check client side to debug. Throw a js event.preventDefault on form submit and try jquery serialize your form to see what the data looks like before you get server side. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @jomin_george94. can you share the db structure and data as sql rather than screenshots, I'm sure that i can help you with this..